# Handlebars variable working when it placed on index.hbs page, but isn't working, when I connect it with <script>

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, handlebars.js

In my controller I set `myId` variavle:

```
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
    res.render('index',{
         myId: req.user._id,
    });
});
```

When I am trying to use it in **index.hbs**:

```
<script>
    alert("{{myId}}"); //58f560395ff25d09fc382448 (works fine)
</script>
```

But when I am connecting script from my scripts folder:

```
<script src="public/js/script.js"></script>
```

And in my **script.js file** trying to:

```
alert("{{myId}}") // {{myId}} (works bad);
```

It shows me string "myId", how can I use handlebars variables in connected files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because express/handlebars only parses your `index.hbs` and not your script file.

What you can do though is setting a variable in the global scope inside your `index.hbs` and later use that global variable in your script files, like so:

Your `index.hbs`:

```
<body>
  // your html
  <script>
    var myId = "{{ myId }}";
  </script>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
```

Your `script.js`:

```
alert( myId );
```

Comment: Yeah, I found the same solution. But is there no way to use variables directly in connected files?

Comment: You could add a `script.hbs` - but I don't know how your handlebar helper is configured because I guess this will sort of result in `script.html`. But I know of a few CMS systems that have a global object (e.g. WordPress or Drupal)